# Specify different appspec.yml file depending on the CodePipeline being used

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

Basically, we have a repo that contains both a client side project, and a server side project, both require different appspec and buildspec configurations.

Is it even possible to get this setup working in CodePipeline, or are we going to be forced to split the repo into two if we want CodePipeline to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

For the buildspec:  You need to create two separate CodeBuild Projects and set the buildspec property correctly in each of those.  You can run the CodeBuild project actions in the pipeline concurrently.

Comment: The buildspec isn't really an issue, as only the client needs to be built.  The appspec however is a different story.

I'm hoping to do something like this:

`
/client
    /aws/appspec.yml
    /aws/buildspec.yml
/server
    /aws/appsec.yml
`

They will both definitely have different CodeBuild and CodeDeploy setups, but how do we go about storing the 2 appspec.yml files in the same repo?

Comment: What is your deployment technology?  CodeDeploy?  ECS?

Comment: CodeDeploy, CodeBuild and CodePipeline.  We've determined this issue can be dealt with, as the appconfig can technically be shared between both our server and client deployments, but it's obviously not ideal.